# How can I deliver an e-mail to only one recipient but have multiple recipients in the “To” field?

Tags: email, smtp, amazon-ses, postmark

I'm trying to recreate a feature found in Microsoft Office 365. When you send an encrypted e-mail from Office 365, it [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUHuy.png) in the Inbox by GMail interface. Note how the e-mail appears to be sent to multiple people, but the "Delivered-To", "Return-Path", "X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop" headers all have only my e-mail address in them. The UI listing makes it look like multiple people received this e-mail, but I know for a fact that only I received this e-mail.

I'm playing with AWS SES, Postmark, and some manual SMTP message generation. How can I send an e-mail that appears (To/CC fields in an e-mail client) to go to multiple people, but only gets delivered to a single e-mail address?

I've been [reading about](https://serverfault.com/questions/796913/how-can-the-to-and-delivered-to-fields-in-an-email-i-received-be-different) how the "envelope" and "normal" headers can differ, but I can't find any information about how to put this into practice so that I can control who actually receives an e-mail, versus who appears to receives an e-mail. Or is this simply a feature of Microsoft's Exchange e-mail servers? Thank you for your time, in advance.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong (alternate *facts*?), Each one of the people in the TO: receive a copy of the email. It's encrypted separately for each of them (they're not the same message), and you see only your information. I can state this quite clearly, as I receive Outlook 365 encrypted emails regularly (along with several other people involved in projects or planning staff). Every single user in the TO: list (as well as the CC and BCC lists) receives a copy of the email, encrypted or not. If you don't want multiple people to get it, send them individually with one name in the TO list.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @KenWhite. I went over to my co-worker's computers and confirmed the e-mail they received had a different body than the one I received. How is that possible?

Comment: Because they're sent as different emails (differently encrypted). It's intentional. *This document is encrypted. OK. Encrypt and send to recipient #1, encrypt and send to recipient #2, and repeat until all recipients have been sent an encrypted copy.* Non-encrypted emails are handled this way:  *We have a list of recipients, and it's not encrypted. Create an email, dump all the recipients into the email's TO field, and send that one email, and let the server take care of the rest.*

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, @KenWhite!